# End of WCHAR* contains junk

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

i'm working on a small project where i have to manage file I/O (this is something i'm quit new to). I'm using the WIN32 API with unicode as the character-set and therefore store all the file-data using wide-characters, and all strings in the program is  stored using std::wstring. This is the part of function that reads and returns the strings:

```
            //Get the string from file and return it
            //(nChars is the amount of characters to read)
            WCHAR * resultBuffer = new WCHAR[nChars];
            file.read(resultBuffer, nChars); 
            std::wstring result = resultBuffer;
            delete[] resultBuffer;
            return result;
```

However i noticed that result contains a bunch of garbage characters at the end (the entire string is read correctly from file, but with  garbage characters appended at the end). Upon further inspection i noticed that these characters also appear just after resultBuffer gets allocated. Now this wouldn't be a problem if they would be over-written  but just appear to appended, and they get copied to result aswell (meaning result gets more elements than intended), which leads to a lot of problems using them later. I managed to fix the problem by adding some to it:

```
            //Get the string from file and return it
            WCHAR * resultBuffer = new WCHAR[nChars];
            file.read(resultBuffer, nChars);
            std::wstring temp = resultBuffer;
            std::wstring result;
            for (INT i = 0; i < nChars; i++) { //NOTE: This shouldn't be necessary 
                result.push_back(temp.at(i));
            }               
            delete[] resultBuffer;
            return result;
```

This fixes the problem but i feel as though it shouldn't be needed. I suspected it might have something to do with how the read function (std::wifstream::read()) works, but i looked at the documentation for it and found no clue. I don't have much experience with using unicode and wide chars so it might be something obvious that i'm missing, but i'm really out clue. Anyone got any ideas? This is how resultBuffer looks after read() has been called (stackoverflow prints them as some kind of middle-eastern characters, but they appear as some asian ones in visual studio).

- resultBuffer L"\\.\DISPLAY1﷽﷽☐☐ﰾ헏✀耀☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐☐"    wchar_t *

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Remy Lebeau and mksteve for providing great explanations aswell as answers! This is the working code:

```
            //Get the string from file and return it
            std::wstring result;
            result.resize(nChars);
            file.read(&result[0], nChars);
            return result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `std::wstring` constructor that expects a null-terminated `wchar_t*` string, but you are not null-terminating your buffer.  Allocate +1 more wchar and set it to 0:

```
WCHAR * resultBuffer = new WCHAR[nChars+1];
file.read(resultBuffer, nChars); 
resultBuffer[nChars] = L'\0'; 
std::wstring result = resultBuffer;
delete[] resultBuffer;
return result;
```

Alternatively, if you specify the buffer length when constructing the `std::wstring`, you don't need the null terminator:

```
WCHAR * resultBuffer = new WCHAR[nChars];
file.read(resultBuffer, nChars); 
std::wstring result(resultBuffer, nChars);
delete[] resultBuffer;
return result;
```

Either way, you should use `std::vector` to manage the memory buffer instead of using `new[]`/`delete[]` manually:

```
std::vector<WCHAR> resultBuffer(nChars+1);
file.read(&resultBuffer[0], nChars); 
resultBuffer[nChars] = L'\0'; 
return std::wstring(resultBuffer.data());
```

```
std::vector<WCHAR> resultBuffer(nChars);
file.read(&resultBuffer[0], nChars); 
return std::wstring(resultBuffer.data(), nChars);
```

Or, you can get rid of the buffer altogether and just read directly into the `std::wstring` itself:

```
std::wstring result;
result.resize(nChars);
file.read(&result[0], nChars); // or result.data() in C++17
return result;
```

Comment: With C++17 you can also write immediately into a `std::wstring`, by passing the result of [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) into `file.read()`.

Comment: Prior to C++17, you can use the string's `operator[]` instead.

Comment: If you use `std::vector` there's no need to set the terminator yourself, it will be default-initialized to zero already.

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes, and that is one thing I don't like about `std::vector` - no way to allocate its buffer without it initializing new elements. For  raw memory buffers, default-initializing can be a waste of time. Unless you use `reserve()` and then `push_back()` the elemetns individually, which is not good for file I/O.

Comment: I'm in complete agreement about the unnecessary overhead of `std::vector`. But I suppose that's why they invented `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have read n characters from a buffer, the mechanism to create a `std::string` is to use the sized constructor

```
file.read(resultBuffer, nChars);
std::wstring temp(resultBuffer, nChars);
```

This is slightly difference from null-terminating your input, as it allows resultBuffer to include L'\0', which becomes part of the new string.  If this is not correct, then ensure the data is null-terminated after the number of bytes read from the `file.read`